Relation between the adjoint operator $T^\times$ and the Hilbert adjoint operator $T^*$: Kreyszig. A question about the norm.
We show that such a relation exists in the case of a bounded linear operator $T\colon X \to Y$ if $X$ and $Y$ are Hilbert spaces, say $X=H_1$ and $Y=H_2$. In this case we first have $$T\colon H_1\to H_2$$ and $$T^\times\colon H_2^*\to H_1^*$$ where the adjoint operator $T^\times$ of the given operator $T$ is defined by $$T^\times g=f $$ and $$g(Tx)=f(x),$$ where $f\in H_1^*$ and $g\in H_2^*$. Now, since $f$ and $g$ are functionals on Hilbert spaces, they have Riesz representation, say, $$f(x)=\langle x, x_0\rangle\quad (x_0\in H_1)$$ and $$g(y)=\langle y, y_0\rangle\quad (y_0\in H_2)$$ and we know also that $x_0$ and $y_0$ are uniquely determined by $f$ and $g$, respectively. This defines operators
$$A_1\colon H_1^* \to H_1\quad \text{by}\quad A_1f=x_0,$$
$$A_2\colon H_2^* \to H_2\quad \text{by}\quad A_2g=y_0$$
We observe that $A_1$ and $A_2$ are bijective and isometric.
We observe also that $A_1$ and $A_2$ are isometric since $$\lVert A_1f \rVert = \lVert x_0 \rVert =\lVert f \rVert.$$
It is simple to prove that $A_1$ and $A_2$ are conjugate lienar. We define $$T^*:= A_1 T^\times A_2^{-1}\colon H_2 \to H_2\quad \text{defined as}\quad T^*y_0:=x_0.$$ It is simple to check that $T^*$ is linear adn that $T^*$ is indeed the Hilbert - adjoint operator of $T$.
It can be proven that $$\lVert T^\times \rVert = \lVert T \rVert.\tag1$$ The autor says that $$\lVert T^* \rVert= \lVert T \rVert\tag2$$ follows from $(1)$ and the isomtry $A_1$ and $A_2$.
My difficulty is precisely in trying $(2)$, could someone give me some suggestions?
My attempt
Since $A_1$ and $A_2$ are isometries we have that $\lVert A_1 \rVert = \lVert A_2 \rVert=1$, then we habe that $$\lVert T^* \rVert= \lVert A_1 T^\times A_2^{-1}\rVert\le \lVert A_1 \rVert \lVert T^\times\rVert \lVert A_2^{-1} \rVert =\lVert T^\times\rVert.$$
As for the other inequality, I have no idea.

Well \begin{align*}\|T^{*}\|&= \sup_{\|f\|=1}\| T^{*}f\| \\
&=\sup_{\|f\|=1}\|A_1 T^{\times}A_2 ^{-1}f\| \\
&= \sup_{\|f\|=1}\|T^{\times}A_2 ^{-1}f\| \\
&= \sup_{\|g\|=1}\|T^{\times}g\| \\
&= \| T^{\times}\| \end{align*}
Using $A_1$ is an isometry at the third equal and that $A_2$ is at the fourth equal.
